# Adding a request.user in a ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a request.user to a manytomany field to create an item. But I receive this error:

TypeError at /api/v1/movies/
'User' object is not iterable

Models.py
class Movie(models.Model):

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='movies')
```

views.py

```
# Create a new movie
def post(self, request):
    serializer = MovieSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owners=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment and updated question, the desired behavior *is* multiple users.  Assuming that your `MovieSerializer` is a subclass of `ModelSerializer` *and* that you have used the default (`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`) binding for the `owners` serializer field, you should be able to add the `requestor` in the initial data:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = MovieSerializer(data=dict(request.data, owners=[request.user.id]))
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    ...
```

**NOTE:** since `owners` is a `ManyToMany` relation, you need to stick the user in an array, and for serialization this needs to be the `pk` of the user, not the object.

Comment: I make an update in the code, correctiong the name creator to owners. A movie can have several owners. My question in itself is how I add that user when creating the item. (Modify, Delete and Consult work perfectly). 
I think my problem is in this line serializer.save (owners = request.user)

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much bro

Comment: You're welcome.  If it works, can you accept the answer?